# zeromq on embedded cortexM3 platform

Tags: embedded, zeromq, cortex-m, freertos

Does anyone have already implemented zeroMQ as reliable message solution on cortexM3 nodes? I'm trying to understand if it is possible and to have a memory footprint idea of this. I will have freeRTOS OS maybe.
Thanks for ideas and suggestions.
Nicola

Comment: Any results there? Is a fascinating topic. Since RIOT has a complete 6LoWPAN stack, it should be possible, if zeroMQ does not use malloc etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/zeromq-dev@lists.zeromq.org/msg12146.html) on the zeromq-dev list.  It seems the 0MQ source makes extensive use of POSIX API, so would take some porting to be supported on a non POSIX OS.  Moreover it requires a TCP/IP stack which may have a larger footprint that 0MQ itself.

For a port FreeRTOS may not be a good starting point - you'd either have to implement a porting layer to map the POSIX API calls to your RTOS and network stack, or modify the 0MQ source directly (which would make accepting updates problematic).

There are a number of RTOS with POSIX or POSIX-like APIs. Amongst free/open-source RTOS [NuttX](https://nuttx.apache.org/) may be a better bet.  It has a POSIX like API and a BSD sockets API stack.

Comment: well, thanks for suggestions. I'm just wondering if there is something else than FreeRTOS that can give me primitives needed for ZeroMQ or do I have to use a POSIX OS? Do I have to use a OS or just a TCP/IP stack?

Comment: @user3162481: see the update to my answer which addresses your comment.