# Cross compiling pyzmq fails because the setup picks up the x86 compiler automatically

Tags: python, cross-compiling, zeromq, python-wheel, pyzmq

I'm trying to cross compile the pyzmq library for my stm32mpu board and I'm facing the issue below.

```py
/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cffi_modules'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running configure
{'libraries': ['zmq'], 'include_dirs': ['/home/Documents/arch_libzmq/include'], 'library_dirs': ['/home/Documents/arch_libzmq/lib'], 'runtime_library_dirs': ['/home/Documents/arch_libzmq/lib'], 'extra_link_args': []}
Warning: Skipping zmq version check
************************************************
building 'zmq.backend.cython._zmq' extension
arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fPIC -DHAVE_SYS_UN_H=1 -I/home/Documents/arch_libzmq/include -Izmq/utils -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o
cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include/python3.10" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]
zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_3zmq_7backend_6cython_4_zmq_5Frame_16set’:
zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.c:9675:12: warning: variable ‘__pyx_v_routing_id’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 9675 |   uint32_t __pyx_v_routing_id;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In function ‘__Pyx_ssize_strlen’,
    inlined from ‘__pyx_pf_3zmq_7backend_6cython_4_zmq_5Frame_14get’ at zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.c:9347:17,
    inlined from ‘__pyx_pw_3zmq_7backend_6cython_4_zmq_5Frame_15get’ at zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.c:9117:13:
zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.c:36018:18: warning: argument 1 null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull]
36018 |     size_t len = strlen(s);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:30,
                 from zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.c:35:
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/string.h: In function ‘__pyx_pw_3zmq_7backend_6cython_4_zmq_5Frame_15get’:
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/string.h:407:15: note: in a call to function ‘strlen’ declared ‘nonnull’
  407 | extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
      |               ^~~~~~
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o -L/home/Documents/arch_libzmq/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/home/Documents/arch_libzmq/lib -lzmq -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/Documents/STM/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

If you see the logs, it first picks up the correct arm-ostl compiler and then again it picks up the x86 compiler below. I've compiled the libzmq and added the path in ZMQ_PREFIX. Also, here's my setup.cfg

```
[global]
skip_check_zmq = True

[build_ext]
; library_dirs =
; include_dirs =
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong or missing here, any help is appreciated!

Edit 1 : I'm running this on x86_64 with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Cross-compiling feels like a very unusual (and hence untested) workflow.  Zmq has a large number of dependencies on the host systems libc which would make this feel even more likely to fail than a less complicated package.  Have you seen https://github.com/benfogle/crossenv? But more details would help, e.g. where would the socket API be coming from on the microcontroller

Comment: On which OS and architecture etc are you running this?

Comment: My bad, Ubuntu 22.04 - x86_64

Comment: that's the host's OS/arch, and hence often of less importance.  what about the target device?  also, what command did you actually run, and what steps did you take before running it?  the warning from `-Wpoison-system-directories` suggests you've got things configured correctly, but without knowing what you've already done it's difficult suggest anything

Comment: The target device is a STM32MP134-dk that has an 32 bit arm cortex-a7 processor.
I set the env variables that points to the include and lib dirs of the STM's sdk.
And then I made the changes in the setup.cfg file like above.
Ran setup.py build

Comment: cross compiling tends to be remarkably complicated as most code is targeting the the system it's being compiled on.  have you checked out that `crossenv` package I pointed to above?  as another pointer, the `distcc` project is another project that is often used when cross-compiling (compiling across hosts often needs the same isolation between host/target) even if you're just using it to compile locally

Comment: just had a search and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947702/1358308 which might have some more pointers